# Error receiving inputs

Tags: c

I have often seen cases where in a series of printf statements that ask for an input, certain 
statements do not accept an input, i.e.

```
printf_statement1:

printf_statement2: /*Enter input here*/
```

i.e. before the user enters an input for *statement1*, *statement2* is printed, that allows the user to enter an input, and then repeats the same with *statement3* & *statement4*.

What prompts such a case?

I encounterd this, but not any more, in:

```
 printf("\n\n\t\tName: ");
 scanf("%s", name); //initially used gets
 printf("\n\n\t\tType: ");     
 scanf("%c", &type);
 printf("\n\n\t\tAddress: ");      //initially used gets
 scanf("%s", address);
 printf("\n\n\t\tDate - of - Birth: ");
 scanf("%s", dob); //initially used gets
```

*Output:*

```
Name:
Type: I enter something!
Address:
Date - of - Birth: I enter something!
```

Comment: To clarify: you're saying that you executed the given code previously, and it didn't in fact prompt you to provide input for Name or Address, but now it does?

Comment: Yes. Wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Sometimes in cases like these, it is helpful to call [`fflush()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) on [`stdin`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdin) before reading from it:

```
char name[40+1];
printf("\n\tName: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%40s", name);
```

Depending on the circumstances, there may be a newline in the input buffer that causes your first [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) to get skipped (given no input).

Also note that you should specify the size of the buffer in [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) as to avoid [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

A format specifier for scanf looks like this:

```
%[*][width][modifiers]type
```

> > width: Specifies the maximum number of characters to be read in the current reading operation

Thus, the `%40s` specifies that only 40 characters may be read in to the string. Note that the buffer is 41 characters, leaving room for the NULL terminator.

**Edit**: Some sources (like [this](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351) and [this](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-57.html)) say that you should avoid calling `fflush(stdin)` and it is incorrect. *However*, the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) states:

> > For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.
> >
> > Conforming to C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008.
> >     The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams. Most other implementations behave the same as Linux.

**Additionally**: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) says nothing about calling `fflush(stdin)` other than the following:

> > If the stream is open for input, fflush clears the contents of the buffer.

One would think that if calling `fflush(stdin)` was such a problem, one of the two largest sources of documentation on `fflush` would have mentioned this.

Comment: What do you call the "%40s"? Any resource might be helpful.

Comment: How can you flush stdin - do you mean stdout?

Comment: As I understand the question, his `scanf`s are not getting input data. If there were a newline in the *input* buffer, then that could be the case.

Comment: The OP is not missing *output* data, (as I understand) so that's why I'm not suggestion to flush `stdout`

Comment: Calling `fflush` on an input stream invokes *undefined behavior*. It's not guaranteed to remove any pending characters from the input stream; it's not guaranteed to do *anything* meaningful.

Comment: so, fflush(stdin) is to use with care. it can cause bugs later, difficult to debug...

Comment: I have used this plenty of times, and seen no anomalies.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I'm going by the C language standard.  7.19.5.2 - "2 If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"  Emphasis mine.

Comment: The man page *does* mention it; it tells you that "The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams." Calling `fflush(stdin)` makes your code non-portable -- and there are perfectly portable ways to do the same thing. If you've seen no anomalies, it's probably because you haven't used a system where `fflush(stdin)` misbehaves; can you be certain your code will never be run on such a system?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is already marked as answered, but as `fflush(stdin)` makes me cringe I wanted to post an alternative to clearing `stdin`:

```
void clear_stdin(void)
{
   int c;
   do {
      c = fgetc(stdin);
   } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

This will clear any `char`s up until a new line or until `EOF` is encountered. (You could just stick the body and condition of the `do..while` into the condition of a `while` loop, but I prefer to write it that way.)

It'd be useful to call that function for example after wanting to read in a single `char`, to prevent subsequent prompts from seeming to be skipped if the user enters more than 1 character.

Also consider using `fgets()` or providing a width specifier with `scanf()` in order to prevent overflows.

Answer (score 2):

to replace fflush(stdin) in "Jonathon Reinhart" answer , i suggest this function, which is standard compliant :

```
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;

    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: How is my answer not "standard compliant"? Have I not provided sufficient documentation?

Comment: the behavior of fflush(stdin) is undifined according to the standard. that's what I mean. so it have to be used with care or not to be used to avoid futur possible bugs, because you dont know what could be done of your code in the futur. But, of course, you provided a number of valuable information. (and i voted up for your detailed answer)

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that the `"%c"` conversion specifier doesn't skip over whitespace.  Suppose you type "Joe" for the name; the input stream will contain the characters 'J', 'o', 'e', '\n'.  The first call to `scanf` looks for a string (`"%s"` conversion specifier); it will consume 'J', 'o', and 'e', and leave the '\n' in the input stream.  In response to the next prompt, you type a character like 'A', so the input stream now contains '\n', 'A', '\n'.  The next call to `scanf` looks for a single character; it will consume the first newline and return, leaving 'A' and '\n' in the input stream.

Rather than flushing `stdin` (which is *not* a well-defined operation according to the language definition), it's better to avoid using the `"%c"` conversion specifier for interactive input; frankly, it's better to avoid using `scanf` for interactive input and use `fgets` instead.

A quick and dirty solution would be to change the type of `type` from a simple `char` to an array of `char` and read it as a string:

```
char type[2];
...
fgets(type, sizeof type, stdin);
```

This will skip over any newlines stuck in the input stream without having to flush anything.  Then you'd just use `type[0]` for your type value.

**Edit**

If you don't want to change the type of `type`, you can do something like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
while ((type = fgetc(stdin)) && isspace(type))
  ;
```

which will read individual characters from `stdin` until it sees a non-whitespace character.