# Reading a string of unknown length from user (works once and stops)

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, realloc

Here is my code:

```
char* get_string()
{
    #define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1000
    char *input=NULL;
    char  buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];

        fgets(buffer,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        if((input=realloc(input,strlen(buffer)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory for string.");
            return NULL;
        }
        strncpy(input,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    return input;
}
```

The 1st time I'm calling the function is works OK, the second time it will return garbage and the program exists with some error.

OK so following the suggestions I edited the code:

```
char* get_string()
{
    #define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1000
    char *input=NULL;
    char  buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];

        if(fgets(buffer,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin)==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error reading string.");
            return NULL;
        }
        if((input=malloc(strlen(buffer)+1))==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory for string.");
            return NULL;
        }
        strncpy(input,buffer,sizeof(input));

    return input;
}
```

In main I have:

```
while(1)
{
tmp_arr_ptr=get_string();
printf("%s",tmp_arr_ptr);
}
```

However I see the same behavior as before.

UPDATE - changed to strcpy(input,buffer); and now it works fine!

Comment: `realloc(input,strlen(buffer))` should be `realloc(input,strlen(buffer)+1)`. +1 for `'\0'`. and use `strcpy`

Comment: `sizeof(input)` will be the size of the pointer, and not the length of the buffer to which it points.  Use `strdup` instead of `malloc/strncpy` as suggested below.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - strcpy did all the difference. I don't understand why to be honest. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `realloc` should be to `strlen(buffer)+1` to accommodate the `NUL` at the end of the string.
2. Whilst it's harmless here, your `strncpy` should be setting the maximum amount of bytes to copy to the size of the destination buffer not the size of the source buffer.
3. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour - see [fflush(stdin) ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604575/fflushstdin-ansi-c)
4. Why bother with `realloc` if `input` is always `NULL` before? Just use `malloc()`. Or better simply `strdup` the buffer.
5. Check the return value of `fgets` against `NULL`.

Comment: Also `strncpy(input,buffer,sizeof(input));` is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the end of your buffer because of the terminating `NULL`.  You need to allocate `strlen(buffer) + 1` bytes. Also there is no need for `strncpy()` since you already know you have allocated enough space.

More thoughts: `realloc()` is awkward for this purpose. For one thing it preserves the original buffer's contents, which could mean an unnecessary copy. Also there is no need to reallocate unless the string is longer than the previous one -- you can reuse the buffer.