# Increasing Size of Struture W/ Realloc (ERROR On the second Increase)

Tags: c, dynamic, structure, realloc

I am a begginer programmer trying to do a project for a class on college that requires the use of dynamic strutures.
My problem:
I use realloc to increase the size of my struture and it works the first time, but not on the second. the auxiliary pointer wich I use to recieve the new increased struture seems to get the value NULL on the second time.

Here's my code so far:

funtion where I try to increase structure:

```
TList *addToQueue (TList *plist, int *counter, char departure)
{
    TList *auxiliary;
    auxiliary = NULL;

    auxiliary = realloc(plist,(*counter+1)*sizeof(TList));

    if (auxiliary == NULL)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Memory");
        cleanstdin();
    }
    else
    {
        plist = auxiliary;
        plist[*counter].departure = departure;

        do{
        printf("\nPoint of Arrival: ");
        plist[*counter].arrival = checkMenuOption(OPTIONSLOC);
        }while(plist[*counter].arrival == '\0');

        printf("\nNumber of passengers:");
        plist[*counter].numberOfPassengers = readIntenger(MIN_SEATS, MAX_SEATS);

        (*counter) ++;

        printf("\nTicket Purchased successfully");
        cleanstdin();

    }
    return plist;
}
```

How I'ts declared above main:

```
TList *addToQueue (TList *plist, int *counter, char departure);
```

How I call in main:

char departure;

```
            departure = sellTicketsMenu ();

            switch (departure)
            {
            case 'A':
            {
                ListA = addToQueue (ListA, &counterA, departure);
                cleanstdin();
            }
            break;
            case 'B':
            {
                ListB = addToQueue (ListB, &counterB, departure);
                cleanstdin();
            }
            break;
            case 'C':
            {
                ListC = addToQueue (ListC, &counterC, departure);
                cleanstdin();
            }
            break;
            }
```

Other notes: readintenger - basic funtion to read intenger from keyboard
cleanstdin - basic clear standarin function
checkmenuoption - funtion to check the option from menus
counters - counters to help with the index of the struture

If you need anything else to understand or to help me please do let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is clear standard input? why? And do you say that `realloc` is returning `NULL` becase the `"Insuf..."` message is printed or why?

Comment: Clear standard is just to avoid any errors when recieiving data from the user and to help create like ''pause'' moments, don't mind that to much, it's not that really important.

Comment: I say that it's returning NULL beacause I have an If condition positioned beneath the realloc to see if it did what it was supposded to do. My teachers said If it returns NULL it means that something ocurred and it wasn't able to increase the struture

Comment: It's just that I suspect you have a `fflush(stdin)` which has [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11604639/1983495).

Comment: Does `cleanstdin()` clear the screen too?

Comment: No. It's like fflush but my teacher uses a mac so we have to do universal codding so that it suits all os.

Comment: So you see `"Insufficient Memory"` in the output on the second call?

Comment: Yep only on the second time forward. The first its fine.

Comment: Please post your full `main` function, or see my answer, may be that's it.

Comment: are counterA, counterB, and counterC all initialized to 0?

Comment: this line: 'printf("Insufficient Memory");' should probably be preceded by: 'perror("realloc failed");'  so the actual problem description and the failure event are recorded on stderr

Answer (score 1):

1. Better to post *here* rather than off-site
2. Off-site code (posted in deleted answer) calls `reallloc()`, via `addToQueue()`, with a pointer that has all ready been free'd.

   ```
    case 'C':
      ...
      free(ListA);
      switch (optionMTI) {
        case 'A': {
          ...
          ListA = addToQueue (ListA, &counterA, departure);
   ```

Problem is re-use of a free'd pointer.
If code is to re-use a pointer after `free()`, be sure to assign it to `NULL`.

```
            // Fixed code  
            free(ListA);
            ListA = NULL;  // add
            ...
            ListA = addToQueue (ListA, &counterA, departure);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation which cannot be confirmed because of the lack of source code is that the passed parameter `counter` is not initialized or `list` is not set to `NULL` before the first call.

You must initialize it to `0`, a typical for loop would look like

```
int counter;
int i;
int numberOfStructs;
TList *list;

counter = 0; /* <--- this is the important part */
numberOfStructs = SOME_NUMBER_MAY_BE_FROM_INPUT;
list = NULL;
for (i = 0 ; i < numberOfStructs ; ++i)
    list = addToQueue (list, &counter, departure);
```

in your case you could just try

```
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0;
int counterC = 0;
```

at the `counter*` variables definition.

Comment: counters are initiallized at 0 already, anymore thoughts? need more code?

Comment: @UnknownChar yes more code please. I wouln't like to leave this answer as is or delete it.