# Inconsistent output despite using exact same input

Tags: c

I'm very new to C, and programming in general, so I apologise in advance if my problem is very simple to solve. I've searched through similar questions but none answer my specific issue.

I'm doing an exercise which asks to write a program that prints all even numbers between two user-input integers. I've expanded on the exercise by ensuring that if the first input is smaller than the second, the program counts up (2, 4, 6, etc.) and counts down (6, 4, 2, etc.) if the first input is larger than the second. I've also given the user an opportunity to keep trying, but despite entering the **exact same inputs** (eg. 2 and 22), the program will randomly print the correct output, or won't print anything.

I've included my code, with output, to help illustrate. Thank you...

```
`#include <stdio.h>

int i, num1, num2;
char agn;

int main(void)
{
        printf("Display all even numbers falling between two integers.\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Enter your first number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &num1);
        printf("\nEnter your second number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &num2);

        printf("\n");

        if (num1 % 2 != 0)
        {
            num1++;
            i = num1;
        }
            // The following if statement decrements if the first number   entered is greater than the second.
            if (i >= num2)
            {
                while (i >= num2 + 2) // Adding 2 to num2 prevents i decrementing to the even number below num2
                    // eg. the printf function below decrements x2, so if the second input is 3, when i = 3 its actual value decrements to 1, therefore making 2 become the last number plotted. This is wrong because 2 is less than the input value of 3. The last number plotted should be 4.
                    printf("%d, ", i -= 2);
            }
            // The else if statement incements if the second number entered is higher than the first, so we must reduce the incremented value of num1 by -2.
            else if (num1 <= num2)
            {
                i = num1 - 2; // num1 was initially incremented by 1. This now decrements num1 by -2
                    while (i <= num2 - 2)
                    printf("%d, ", i += 2);
            }
                    printf("\n\nWould you like to try again? (Y/N): ");
                    scanf(" %c", &agn); // Remember to put a space before %c

                if (agn == 'n')
                        {
                            agn = 'N';
                        }
        }
    while (agn != 'N');

            printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}`
```

Output:
Display all even numbers falling between two integers.

Enter your first number: 2

Enter your second number: 22

2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22,

Would you like to try again? (Y/N): y
Enter your first number: 22

Enter your second number: 2

20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2,

Would you like to try again? (Y/N): y

Enter your first number: 22

Enter your second number: 2

*(---no output---)*

Would you like to try again? (Y/N): y
Enter your first number: 2

Enter your second number: 22

2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22,

Would you like to try again? (Y/N): n

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798071/11639518 speaks to issues with scanf; other similar answers expound further on the fflush that's offered (they offer better options). Have you tried printf debugging to ensure your values are what you expect them to be? Or fgets instead of scanf?

Comment: You only set `i = num1;` if `num` is odd. Move `i = num1;` out of the braces of if-statement.

Comment: Your solution worked Mathias, although I still have another small issue which I'm working on now. I'm pretty sure vgel's answer is spot-on but my level of knowledge needs to improve before I'm able to implement it. Thanks, guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not always initializing `i`. You initialize `i = num1` if the first number is odd, and you initialize `i = num1 - 2` in the incrementing branch, but in the decrementing branch you don't initialize it. Since you ran the incrementing branch first, `i` was left as so:

```
i = num1 - 2; // i = 0
while (i <= num2 - 2) // i <= 20
  printf("%d, ", i += 2); // i is left as 22
```

So when you then run the decrementing loop, `i` is set correctly completely on accident:

```
if (i >= num2) // true, i = 22 from before, num2 = 2
{
    while (i >= num2 + 2) // i >= 4
        printf("%d, ", i -= 2); // i = 2
}
```

But then when you try to run the decrementing loop again right after, `i` is 2, not 22. So you get

```
if (i >= num2) // true, i = 2, num2 = 2
{
    while (i >= num2 + 2) // i >= 4, immediately false
        printf("%d, ", i -= 2); // never runs
}
```

What I would suggest is re-architecting your code into two functions. `main()` should handle the user input and the state of the program (num1, num2) which then get passed to a helper function `printSequence` (or two, `printForward` and `printReverse`) that has a local variable `i`. This will help with this kind of bug, because all the long-lived state will be confined to `main()`.

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed answer, much appreciated. Give me an hour to digest and try out. Cheers... oz

Answer (score 0):

It seems I may have gotten ahead of my abilities with this problem, being only a couple of weeks into learning C. Passing values to helper functions is something I'm going to have to bring myself up to speed with before changing the structure of this program. As a workaround though, I've gone with the solution offered by Mathias, which was to simply remove i = num1; from the if statement braces. This works, although I still have to sort through a couple of issues. That's what I love about this game - the challenges it throws up. Thanks heaps, guys. I really appreciate your help.